# What would another Ubuntu user's default font be?

Tags: fonts, email, restricted-formats

If I send an email from, say, Thunderbird, and have "Helvetica/Arial" set as my default outgoing font, then my assumption is that most of the world will read that email in Helvetica (Apple) or Arial (Windows).

But what if I send that email to another Ubuntu user who does not have the MS core fonts installed? What will the email's font default to? Would Ubuntu override it with something like sans-serif, perhaps?

Comment: That's suppose to happen regardless of the OS, If i send you a File/email/whatever, with a specific font and then you open it and you don't have the font i used the OS will use the closest matching font it can out of your installed fonts.

Comment: ... unless they have set a font that preceeds any other font (all my mails show up as `courier new` ;)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Uri Herrera & Rinzwind:

> That's suppose to happen regardless of the OS, If i send you a
>   File/email/whatever, with a specific font and then you open it and you
>   don't have the font i used the OS will use the closest matching font
>   it can out of your installed fonts
>
> unless they have set a font that preceeds any other font (all my mails
>   show up as courier new

So in most cases, sending the letter with a specific font will be displayed with that same font. In the case of not having that specific font, a similar one will be appointed.